# Can Lights' bar hangers not long enough to span trusses (New construction)

Tags: electrical

Kitchen remodel.  Using the previous (new construction) can lights but I got rid of the lowered ceiling and re-positioned the lights.  With where I'd like to place them now, the arms (bar hangers) from the lights cannot reach between the trusses.

This is because I want the lights right up next to one of the trusses.  It fits fine up to the close one, but cannot reach the far one. Distance between trusses is 24" center to center.

Ideas?  Can I just secure it to a truss on one side and leave the other side unsecured?
[image]

Comment: run 2 boards perpendicular to the "trusses", then a board perpendicular to those, giving you a closer nail point. the new wood should look like an `H` from above when done.

Comment: Dan this should be an answer+

Comment: was in a time crunch, but the one below looks plenty acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

Similar to @dandavis' comment, but you probably don't need to run the 3rd board.   Just nail two boards perpendicular to the trusses, spaced about 18" apart, and nail the canned light to those (so the light housing will be rotated 90 degrees from what you are showing in the picture).

Comment: You might want to use screws instead of nails to attach the 2x4s to support the can light. Pounding with a hammer might damage the drywall ceiling.

Comment: Since he has access from the top, I would toenail the boards into the trusses, and that way the ceiling is left untouched.

Comment: I was thinking about using either two or four Simpson Strong Tie right angle connectors screwed into the bottom cords of the trusses. Simpson makes special screws for the attachment of the connectors.